# Pre-build event command line. Failing but not required

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pre-build-event

In visual studio i have set a command line event which works fine.

```
net stop "my windows service"
```

However this event can return a non zero response if the service isn't running. 
I would like visual studio to continue the build even if a non zero response is received.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it just clicked with me. If I add START before my command it will always return a zero because it will launch a new command prompt.

```
start net stop "my windows service"
```